# How to crop tensor in the center in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

The tensor shape is [batch, height, width, channel].
Let's take the tensor as [8, 64, 64, 1], how could I crop it in the center to [8, 56, 56, 1]? Note that the feature 56*56 is center taken from 64*64.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is **tf.image.central_crop**

[Doc link for tf.image.central_crop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/central_crop)

In your instance for working with batched images then you need to use the tf.map_fn function. It allows you to apply a single tensor function to a sequence of functions. For example you might need something like:

```
cropped_image=tf.map_fn(lambda img: tf.image.central_crop(img,0.5), imgin, parallel_iterations=8, name="crop1")
```

This should return your cropped images as a batch as you would usually find flowing through your graph!

Comment: A central_fraction must be given in tf.image.central_crop, I'm worried about that the fraction may not result in the exactly size I want if the size to crop cannot be denoted precisely by fraction.

Comment: You should be fine. A little bit of trial and error should get exactly what you want. I think that Tensorflow will only do the crop based on integer shapes. So you will always be able to have a fraction that matches your desired output!